# Mongo match based on sum of array components

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following schema and I am having trouble returning the data that I want.

```
var Book = new Schema({
    ISBN: String,
    title: String,
    author: String,
    image: String,
    availability: [{zipcode: String,
                    total: Number,
                    loaned: Number
    }]
});
```

I would like to return a random sample of items (maybe 25) in which there are items available.  In this case availability would be defined be the total being greater than the number loaned in at least one of the sets under "availability" (or by looking at the sum of total and loaned in all the sets).  Every time I start, I seem to run into a wall.  Does anyone have any idea if this is possible or how to do it?

Comment: You may need to use `aggregation` for this as a simple `find` simply won't work. You should be able to perform some sort of projection on the documents to find which have a description roughly like `total > loaned`, then `limit` your results to the amount you want. Be sure to take a look at aggregation and research how the aggregation pipeline and operators work. Try it out and come back with a new question if you get stuck, with the aggregation code you've managed so far. You'll be able to get more help then :)

Comment: Thanks @B.Fleming.  I've been working with aggregation and that's where I keep getting stuck.  Any pointers on a good place to look for direction on that?  My schema makes sense to me, but I can't find any comparable ones in examples anywhere and working with the array elements are making it a bit confusing for me.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure about specific resources, unfortunately, just the MongoDB documentation. But I'll give you a hint: `$unwind` will help you with the issue of dealing with the arrays and allow you to handle the array elements individually. There are a lot of useful operators like that floating around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did finally get it working by doing this:

```
db.books.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $addFields: {
                available: {$gt: [{$sum: "$availability.total"}, {$sum: "$availability.loaned"}]}
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {available: true}
        },
        {
            $sample: {size: 25}
        }
    ]
)
```

I'm not sure if there are any downsides to this approach, but with limited testing it does seem to work for me.